# Help, don't know what's wrong with my HTTP multipart POST

Tags: http, post, multipartform-data

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Host: assets.drop.io
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.10) Gecko/2
009042316 Firefox/3.0.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Length: 5728
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD


--------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="api_key"

0b8a12109c3a1bfc4ba94aec926e1f9cfd8bb6f0
--------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="drop_name"

4pgvoxc
--------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version"

2.0
--------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="rachel"; filename="rachel"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

BMv¶
--------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD--
```

The response I get is: Bad Request. And in the HTML of the response there is this:

```
:MultiPartParseError: bad content body:
'
----------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD' should == '----------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD
'></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in your question. The response says that the divider should be `'----------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD '` instead of  `' ----------MalolHCBdarysNYMHZbIvjbD'`

Look at the leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: The spaces look all right but the parser seems to have problems with the preceding line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

The schematic syntax of a [`multipart/form-data` message](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) is as follows:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field 1"

data 1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field 2"

data 2
⋮
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field N"

data N
--boundary--
```

So the inner part boundaries are `--boundary` (`--` followed by the boundary value) and the last is `--boundary--` (`--` followed by the boundary value followed by `--`).

In your case you are just missing the leading `--`.

Comment: +1 counting hyphens is a pain, I prefer my boundaries without extra leading hyphens!